# Filter Tags in Orchard CMS to only Blogs

Tags: orchardcms, tag-cloud

In Orchard CMS, I'm trying to find a way to filter the Tags in the Tag Cloud to return tags only from blog posts. Right now, the Tag Cloud returns tags from all content types.

I'm using the default Tag Cloud in Orchard 1.7.1.

If there is a setting in admin, great, if not, I found a query in TagCloudService.cs. Is this the one I need to edit. If so, can someone help me with the filter I need to add here to include only blog posts

```
tagCounts = _contentManager
                .Query<TagsPart, TagsPartRecord>(VersionOptions.Published)
                .Join<CommonPartRecord>()
                .Where(t => t.Container.Id == containerId)
                .List()
                .SelectMany(t => t.CurrentTags)
                .GroupBy(t => t)
                .Select(g => new TagCount {
                    TagName = g.Key,
                    Count = g.Count()
                })
                .ToList();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the call to `Query` with `.Query().ForPart<TagsPart>().ForType("BlogPost").ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published).Join<TagsPartRecord>()`.

Comment: I have an additional requirement on the filter. The Blog Posts have 3 taxonomy fields associated similar to your tutorial here http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/using-taxonomies-in-orchard [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/using-taxonomies-in-orchard). How can I include filter based on the taxonomy fields.

e.g., The blog posts have a taxonomy field, Article Type. I want only tags from blog posts of a specific article type to be returned in the Tag Cloud.

Comment: That's a new question. I think you'll have to switch to a Hql query for that, and look at the Taxonomy module's service class source code to see how they are performing this kind of query.